# Show that $Y_n$ converges to Y almost surely.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$,... be a sequence of random variables on a probability space ($\Omega$ , F , $\mu$). Assume that there is a random variable Y on the same probability space such that for any $\epsilon$>0, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{\lvert Y_n-Y \lvert > \epsilon \} < \infty.$$ Show that $Y_n$ converges to Y almost surely.

What I believe to be the definition of almost sure convergence is,

$$ P(w: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}Y_n = Y) = P( \bigcup_{\epsilon>0 \ rationals}  \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n > m}^{\infty} \ \{ |Y_n - Y| < \epsilon \}) = 1  $$

Like the answer below suggested. We the apply the Borel-Cantelli Lemma which states

$$ \ If \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n)< \infty, \ then \ P(A_n \ i.o) = P(  \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}\ A_n) = P(\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n = m}^{\infty}A_n)=0.$$
From our assumptions, since we know for any $\epsilon>0$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{\lvert Y_n-Y \lvert > \epsilon \} < \infty$. 
If we define $A_n= {|Y_n -Y|>\epsilon}$, we can say $$P(\bigcup_{\epsilon>0  \ rationals \ } \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n = m}^{\infty} \{|Y_n-Y|> \epsilon \})=0.$$

Thus applying De-Morgans Law we can say, $$ P(\bigcap_{\epsilon>0 \ rationals \ } \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} \{ |Y_n-Y| < \epsilon\}) = 1. $$

This implies $$ P( \bigcup_{\epsilon > 0 \ rationals}\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} \{ |Y_n-Y| < \epsilon\}) = 1. $$

We can also note $$\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} \{ |Y_n-Y| < \epsilon\} \subset  \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n = m}^{\infty} \{|Y_n-Y|> \epsilon \}$$.

Is this enough to show it converges almost surely? I remember being told you also have to show the two sets on both the LHS and RHS have the same elements? If so how would you go about doing this?

Comment: You are not supposed to append an answer to your question as if it was a part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\sum_{n=1}\mathbb P(|Y_n-Y|>\varepsilon)<\infty$, the Borel-Cantelli lemma implies that
$$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} |Y_n-Y|>\varepsilon\right) = 0. $$
From this we conclude that $Y_n\to Y$ a.s.